# Facelets, JSP, Servlets and HTTP/2

Tags: jsp, jsf, servlets, facelets, http2

I know that JSP pages are converted to servlets. And I also know that in the next Java EE 8 there will be the new Servlets 4.0 with support for HTTP/2.

My doubt is about facelets, are they also converted to servlets? Will facelets in JSF 2.3 support HTTP/2?

Comment: BalusC, my second question is not answered in the question you have indicated.

Comment: The answer of the duplicate logically invalidates the second question. HTTP/2 is not Facelets' concern as it is not a Servlet.